# Calm music played after pain destroyed leaf village

Tags: naruto, music

I have been searching for this music for long time, but couldn't find one, what is the music [at time 20.51](https://youtu.be/w2RSAecDuos?t=1251)  when pain destroys the leaf village and everybody are rising after destruction, it's a music like a lady is singing.

This music also played when kaguya first appeard [at time 1.30](https://youtu.be/bhzoY__XVR4?t=90)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name of the song is:
[Shippuu Kumikyoku ( Hurricane Suite )](https://youtu.be/P5Hp42y7gVA)

Artist: Yasuharu Takanashi

Album:Naruto Shippuden OST 1
- Track 28 -

> The main problem is that exactly version of the song used in anime (with women vocals) is very hard to find (maybe impossible), but you can try it, if you want, and have time..

I managed to find one, only choir without music, labeled as unreleased soundtrack:
[Naruto Shippuuden Unreleased Soundtrack - Hurricane Suite (choir only)](https://youtu.be/N3sJjLjBTtA)